# Windows Domain replication monitoring tool

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, replication, active-directory, network-monitoring

I am looking for web-based interface GUI, or some kind of monitoring tool that will show replication status for a domain.

I know I can use [repadmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736571(WS.10).aspx) with various options on the command line to query the status.  I thought about creating a script they could run when they are interested in the status, but they will probably be more interested in some kind of status page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer is a supplement to my other answer to this question.)

Then again, there is a [powershell script here](http://technodrone.blogspot.com/2010/04/monitor-ad-replication-status-with.html), where the guy basically runs as a Cronjob which emails him the status every 4 hours.

Taking his script, it would be fairly easy to (again) run as a cron and [output to html](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730936.aspx), and have your team refresh their page periodically (or Javascript page reload every *X* seconds.)

Comment: This is probably close enough to what I was asking.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question is super-old, but this tool just recently came out, and this post came up while I was searching for it because I couldn't quite remember the name, and so I'll just leave this here in case anyone else passes through looking for this tool like I just did:

[AD Replication Status Tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/23/ad-replication-status-tool-is-live.aspx):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/23/ad-replication-status-tool-is-live.aspx

Answer (score 2):

How about the one that comes with windows support tools, [replmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772954(WS.10).aspx).
But it is not a web gui, with fancy graph and etc.

Comment: They are transitioning to a 2008 domain.  Replmon is no longer recommended for 2008 [ref](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/07/01/getting-over-replmon.aspx).  But replmon is useful.

Comment: ahhh... 2008 ... have not tested replmon on it, but some people has mentioned that they are able to use it without an issue. But probably not on 2k8 R2.

Answer (score 2):

[This article covers the replmon's replacement, repadmin.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/07/01/getting-over-replmon.aspx)

While it fails the first part of your request in being a Web/GUI too, it could fairly easily be incorporated into a script that produces html output.  (It also produces csv output.)

Do you actively need to actively view the current status?  Earlier this year I wrote an [Exchange Monitoring script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/e5dd50bc-5e69-4eb9-b544-221493e12f0d) that I published to the http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us.  On problems (or certain thresholds exceeded), I have it run as a scheduled task which alerts as needed.  (I also duplicated part of it in perl to run from our Linux environment in case a non-fault tolerant part breaks so that the vbs can't alert, the perl/Linux version can.)

I also built a slightly modified version intended to be run manually with reports any problems to the console (instead of email) or simply says "No Issues." (in large friendly letters...)

My point is to ask whether it would be enough simply to be alerted when there's a problem, or if you need something on a screen to look at constantly.

(I can, of course, elaborate as necessary...)

Comment: Couple RepAdmin with a windows-based monitoring framework (Intermapper comes to mind), and you can write a custom probe that uses RepAdmin calls to return key data that is then put into the framework's Web/GUI. Interesting stuff.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Intermapper, but I'm sure that you can monitor Replication with Nagios, Xabbix, Cacti, etc., and they have dashboards or plugins for dashboards (which is what I think you may be going for) available for use

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply.  I am not entirely sure if a GUI was really needed.  A client was asking for replication monitoring so I ask the question here for them.  replmon/repadmin has always been useful enough for me.  I suspect the writing a script that sends out alerts may be good enough.  Mostly I was just asking to see if there was anything already out there that was being commonly used.