# AD Replication Monitor

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, replication

Is there something like Replication Monitor (in Windows 2000) available in Windows 2008 R2? What tool do you use to check replication health?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/169571/windows-domain-replication-monitoring-tool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps a little presumptuous of me to merely post the help file but in short, it's the answer you're after.

Also look at dcdiag.exe for other information regarding DNS since replication relies heavily on your DNS infrastructure being fully operational.

```
C:\repadmin.exe /?


Usage: repadmin <cmd> <args> [/u:{domain\user}] [/pw:{password|*}]
                         [/retry[:<retries>][:<delay>]]
                         [/csv]



Use these commands to see the help:
/?          Displays a list of commands available for use in repadmin and their
        description.

/help       Same as /?

/?:<cmd>    Displays the list of possible arguments <args>, appropriate 
        syntaxes and examples for the specified command <cmd>.

/help:<cmd> Same as /?:<cmd>  

/experthelp Displays a list of commands for use by advanced users only.

/listhelp   Displays the variations of syntax available for the DSA_NAME,
        DSA_LIST, NCNAME and OBJ_LIST strings.  

/oldhelp    Displays a list of deprecated commands that still work but
        are no longer supported by Microsoft.

Supported <cmd> commands (use /?<cmd> for detailed help):  

 /kcc    Forces the KCC on targeted domain controller(s) to immediately 
         recalculate its inbound replication topology.

 /prp    This command allows an admin to view or modify the 
         password replication policy for RODCs.

 /queue  Displays inbound replication requests that the  DC needs to issue 
         to become consistent with its source replication partners.



 /replicate  Triggers the immediate replication of the specified directory
         partition to the destination domain controller from the source DC.

 /replsingleobj Replicates a single object between any two domain
         controllers that have common directory partitions. 

 /replsummary The replsummary operation quickly and concisely summarizes
         the replication state and relative health of a forest.

 /rodcpwdrepl Triggers replication of passwords for the specified user(s) 
         from the source (Hub DC) to one or more Read Only DC's.

 /showattr Displays the attributes of an object.

 /showobjmeta Displays the replication metadata for a specified object
         stored in Active Directory, such as attribute ID, version 
         number, originating and local Update Sequence Number (USN), and 
         originating server's GUID and Date and Time stamp. 

 /showrepl Displays the replication status when specified domain controller
         last attempted to inbound replicate Active Directory partitions.

 /showutdvec displays the highest committed Update Sequence Number (USN)
         that the targeted DC's copy of Active Directory shows as 
         committed for itself and its transitive partners. 

 /syncall Synchronizes a specified domain controller with all replication
          partners.

Supported additional parameters:

 /u:    Specifies the domain and user name separated by a backslash 
        {domain\user} that has permissions to perform operations in 
        Active Directory. UPN logons not supported.  

 /pw:   Specifies the password for the user name entered with the /u 
        parameter.

 /retry This parameter will cause repadmin to repeat its attempt to bind 
        to the target dc should the first attempt fail with one of the 
        following error status:

        1722 / 0x6ba : "The RPC Server is unavailable"
        1753 / 0x6d9 : "There are no more endpoints available from the 
                        endpoint mapper"

 /csv   Used with /showrepl to output results in comma separated
        value format. See /csvhelp


Note: Most commands take their parameters in the order of "Destination or 
  Target DSA_LIST", then a "Source DSA_NAME" if required, and finally the
  NC or Object DN if required.

<DSA_NAME> (or <DSA_LIST>) is a Directory Service Agent binding 
    string. For Active Directory Domain Services, this is simply a network
    label (such as a DNS, NetBios, or IP address) of a Domain Controller. 
    For Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services, this must be a 
    network label of the AD LDS server followed by a colon and the LDAP 
    port of the AD LDS instance

        Examples (AD DS):  dc-01
                           dc-01.microsoft.com

        Examples (AD LDS): ad-am-01:2000
                           ad-am-01.microsoft.com:2000

  <Naming Context> is the Distinguished Name of the root of the NC

        Example: DC=My-Domain,DC=Microsoft,DC=Com
Note: Text (Naming Context names, server names, etc) with International or
  Unicode characters will only display correctly if appropriate fonts and
  language support are loaded.
```

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is super-old, but this tool just recently came out, and this post came up while I was searching for it because I couldn't quite remember the name, and so I'll just leave this here in case anyone else passes through looking for this tool like I just did:

[AD Replication Status Tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/23/ad-replication-status-tool-is-live.aspx):

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/23/ad-replication-status-tool-is-live.aspx

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Lewis. Also see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/07/01/getting-over-replmon.aspx